# How to fix "net/http: TLS handshake timeout" issues on macOS

Tags: macos, go, keychain, tls1.3

I was running into `net/http: TLS handshake timeout` issues with some golang programs on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out in my case it was due to a crazy number of certificates in my system keychain that the system was parsing.

```
security dump-keychain /Library/Keychains/System.keychain | grep "\"alis\"" | wc -l
```

should give you a number < 20 in most cases, and in mine it was > 10000. Deleting these excess certificates was a bit of a pain, but assuming they all have the same name I managed to do it using a script like this:

```
security find-certificate -c "<CERTNAME>" -a -Z /Library/Keychains/System.keychain | \
  sudo awk '/SHA-1/{system("security delete-certificate -Z "$NF)}'
```

where `<CERTNAME>` is replaced with the actual certificate name.